# Popup Display When Phone Rings

Tags: java, android

I want to make a popup when a voice call comes in.
I can write toast messages using broadcast receiver. But how do I add popup instead of toast message?

My Code:

```java
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static AlertDialog alertDialog;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is -",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an AlertDialog using,

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert title");
alertDialog.setMessage("Your alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I couldn't implement the code you provided. Can you help me a little more?

Comment: When I write the code you gave me, it makes a mistake. I want to popup the screen when the phone rings even though the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                showDialog(mContext, "EXTRA_STATE_RINGING");

            }
            if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))) {

                showDialog(mContext, "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK");
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                showDialog(mContext, "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void showDialog(Context context, String message) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

and make static `context` in your `activity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = this;


    }

}
```